# I have enabled scrollbar in high chart.. But its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have enabled scrollbar in high chart.. But its not working..
please check this link

[https://jsfiddle.net/malai/ehts85vw/15/](http://Fiddle)

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/1/... i followed this link... same only i also used in mine code...

Comment: use `highstock.js` instead of `highcharts.js`. https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js

Comment: I have developed graph using highchart...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/1/ here they used highchart,js only...

Comment: he use `highstock.js`, see this line `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>`

Comment: If i use highstock getting error..

Comment: what error? try `https` --> `https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined....

Comment: Hey bro... super working fine ya

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbar works only with highstock, please check the following link http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar